# Is there a way to give initial value in an instance in property initializer dynamically using SwiftUI and Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Hi I am currently making a dating app's chat page that you can have different rooms for every match using SwiftUI and Cloud Firestore.

I would like to show different chat room every time you tap different user on the top page depending on the matchId.

For now, I need to type the right one in the View file in order to make it work correctly, however, Id like to assign it dynamically.

How can I add the correct matchId to the instance in the View file? Or, should I try different ways?

First, this is the top page.

```
VStack{
         Text("Match Users")
         List(self.shareData.matchUserArray){ user in
            NavigationLink(destination: MessageView(matchUserInfo: user)){
               HStack{
                  Text(user.name)
                  Text(user.age)
               }
             }
           }
         }
```

And this is the View file. Without typing "Ll73RINefGxEcYQJoWSE" in the MessageViewModel instance and instead giving it "", I can see the messages in the debug area but don't see any in List.

```
struct MessageView: View {
    var matchUserInfo: User

    @ObservedObject var msgVM = MessageViewModel(matchId: "Ll73RINefGxEcYQJoWSE")

    @EnvironmentObject var shareData : ShareData
    @State var text = ""

    @State var matchId = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List(self.msgVM.messages, id: \.id){ i in
                if i.fromUser == self.shareData.currentUserData["id"] as? String ?? ""
                {
                    MessageRow(message: i.msg, isMyMessage: true)
                } else if  i.toUser == self.shareData.currentUserData["id"] as? String ?? ""
                {
                    MessageRow(message: i.msg, isMyMessage: false)
                }
                }
            .onAppear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none }
            .onDisappear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine }

            HStack{
                TextField("message here", text: $text).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).padding()
                Button(action: {
                    if self.text.count > 0 {
                          self.msgVM.sendMsg(msg: self.text, toUser: self.matchUserInfo.id, fromUser: self.shareData.currentUserData["id"] as! String, matchId: self.msgVM.matchId)

                        self.text = ""
                    }

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                }.padding(.trailing)
            }

        }
        .navigationBarTitle("\(self.matchUserInfo.name)", displayMode: .inline)
            .onAppear{
                DispatchQueue.global().async{
                self.getMatchId(partner: self.matchUserInfo)
                }
                _ = MessageViewModel(matchId: self.matchId)

        }


        .onDisappear{
          print(self.msgVM.messages)
        }
    }

    func getMatchId(partner: User){
        Firestore.firestore().collection("MatchTable").document(self.shareData.currentUserData["id"] as? String ?? "").collection("MatchUser").whereField("MatchUserId", isEqualTo: partner.id).getDocuments { (snap, err) in
            if let snap = snap {
                for id in snap.documents{
                    self.msgVM.matchId = id.data()["MatchRoomId"] as? String ?? ""
                    _ = MessageViewModel(matchId: self.msgVM.matchId)
                    self.matchId = self.msgVM.matchId
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Also this is the firebase part.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Message: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var msg: String
    var fromUser: String
    var toUser: String
    var date: Timestamp
    var matchId : String
}


class MessageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var datas = FirebaseData()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    @Published var matchId:String

    @Published var messages = [Message]()

    init(matchId: String){
        self.matchId = matchId

        self.db.collection("Messages").whereField("matchId", isEqualTo: self.matchId).order(by: "date").addSnapshotListener { (snap, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let snap = snap {
                for i in snap.documentChanges {

                    if i.type == .added{
                        let toUser = i.document.get("toUser") as! String
                        let fromUser = i.document.get("fromUser") as! String
                        let message = i.document.get("message") as! String
                        let id = i.document.documentID
                        let date = i.document.get("date") as! Timestamp
                        let matchId = i.document.get("matchId") as! String

                        self.messages.append(Message(id: id, msg: message, fromUser: fromUser, toUser: toUser, date: date, matchId: matchId))

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }




    func sendMsg(msg: String, toUser: String, fromUser: String, matchId: String){

        let data = [
            "message": msg,
            "toUser": toUser,
            "fromUser": fromUser,
            "date": Timestamp(),
            "matchId": matchId
            ] as [String : Any]

        Firestore.firestore().collection("Messages").addDocument(data: data){ error in
            if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print("Sent message")
        }


}
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

All you should really need is to construct your `ObservedObject` in an `init` function:

```swift
let matchUserInfo: User

@ObservedObject private var msgVM: MessageViewModel

init(_ user: User) {
    self.matchUserInfo = user
    self._msgVM = ObservedObject(initialValue: MessageViewModel(matchId: user.matchId))
}
```

Assuming, of course, that the `matchId` you care about is passed in via your `User` type. You know your data structures better than I do, the key here is to simply create your observed object based on your passed in `User`.

Comment: I added some changes to the elements of matchUserArray so that every passed-in user has matchId, and everything has started working well. Thanks a lot it was so helpful! @Procrastin8